# Windows Phone 7 Dialog

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-interface, windows-phone

How can I show a dialog message, similar to `MessageBox`, which have just the "Cancel" button and can be closed by the application.

The idea is to show the dialog while the application retrieves data from a server, allowing the user to cancel this request, and closing the dialog once the request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

I recall having a very similar problem in the past. I don't think there is a dialog message "out of the box" that works like that. The way I solved this was by writing a class that modeled this sort of behavior in a window and having the application spawn an instance of the window.

Answer (score 0):

The silverlight message box blocks code execution while it is open so it is not possible to close it. However you can use an XNA messagebox in Silverlight which is asynchronous

[This explains its use in depth](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/delivering-message-using)

You can probably then call [EndShowMessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.guide.endshowmessagebox.aspx) for your purposes.

Comment: It was almost what i needed, by following [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2011/04/19/building-a-better-messagebox-for-wp7-with-the-help-of.aspx) I was able to show the dialog I needed, however, I still dont know how to close it.

Comment: The BeginShowMessageBox method is asynchronous so you code continues to execute after if is called. You want to close the messagebox after the datatransfer is complete so it is at the end of this method that you want to call EndShowMessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

if your intention is to let the user know that something is loading and that they should wait. you should use a progressbar instead.

[How to: Create a Custom Indeterminate Progress Bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442303%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)